# C# string trimming

Tags: c#, string

I am having trouble on how i should trim this string. I want everything after the last '/' to be deleted, but there are multiple '/'.

Example:

From:`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/randomcrap.html`

To: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

String trimming can be done using many of the built in string utlitites.

First you want the `LastIndexOf` the "/" character in the string, and then you want use the `Substring` method from the index of `0` (start of the string) to the index of the `/` character. Now this will return everything to the last `/` if you want to include the slash you have to add one more index.

```
        static string getToLastSlash(string inString)
        {
            var index = inString.LastIndexOf('/');
            if (index == -1)
                throw new Exception("/ not found in string");

            return inString.Substring(0, index + 1);
        }
```

The `LastIndexOf()` method will return the last index of a specific character or string provided. If the `LastIndexOf()` method does not evaluate a match the result will be `-1`. Given the fact that you could have a non-match, you must first check if the match result is `-1`. In the above method we simply throw an exception however your application may have an alternative method to handle this situation.

If the match is greater that `-1` then you can assume a match was found. When a match was found you can use the `Substring()` method to parse all the characters in the string starting at position `0` to the `index+1`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a regular expression [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with an [end (`$`) anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w.aspx#End).

```
var res = Regex.Replace(input,
    @"[^/]+$", // match all the non-slashes anchored to the end of input
    "");       // replace any matched characters with nothing

// and make sure to use "res"
```

I prefer to use a regular expression for tasks like this - because *I* find it simpler and it can avoid an extra conditional guard "for free" - but make sure to understand the mechanics of the approach used.

Comment: `Repace <-> Replace ?`

Comment: @MechanicalObject I had to Replace my Repace. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Combining `string.Substring` and `string.LastIndexOf` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this by using Uri class

```
Uri parent = new Uri(uri, ".");
```

Comment: cool, I tried that and it works except for handling extra slashes (which I think he was asking about), but it's very close and simple so +1

Answer (score 1):

Most simple way would probably be

```
string myURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/randomcrap.html";
string str = myURL.Substring(0, myURL.LastIndexOf('/'));
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

which will output

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

Comment: Just be aware that input like "foobar" (no slashes) will result in an ArgumentOutOfRange exception as `Substring(0, -1)` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Split` the char `'/'` then convert it to a `List<string>` and remove the last item and finally reunite the parts using `string.Join`

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/randomcrap.html";
var b = url.Replace("http://", "").Split('/').ToList(); //replace "html://" to avoid problems with the split
b.RemoveAt(b.Count-1); //last index

var result = "http://" + string.Join("/", b) + "/";
```

`result` equals to `"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/"`

This will allow you to remove any part you wish.
Don't forget you could also use `b.RemoveRange(int index, int count)`;

Comment: `string.LastIndexOf(char)` will already find the last index of a character.

Comment: @Cyral by referring to "last index" in the comment, I meant the last index inside the list

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) like this

```
string str = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/randomcrap.html";
string final = RemoveAfterLastChar(str, '/');

public string RemoveAfterLastChar(string input, char c)
{
    var index = input.LastIndexOf(c);

    if (index != -1)
        return input.Substring(0, index + 1);
    else
        return input;
}
```

Or, if the format is always going to be the same as your example, you could use [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx).

```
input = Path.GetDirectoryName(input);
```

Comment: I've used the GetDirectoryName approach on "native" paths, but am always hesitant to use it on URIs for some reason (irrelevant stigma, maybe).

Comment: @user2246674 - I agree, I usually stick to the first method. I just posted it as an alternative in case OP is confident that the format is the same all the time (i.e. there's a filename at the end).

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{   
    Console.WriteLine (TrimLastPart("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/randomcrap.html"));
    Console.WriteLine (TrimLastPart("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask//randomcrap.html"));
}

enum State
{
    SlashNotEncountered,
    SlashEncountered,
    BuildingResult
}

string TrimLastPart(string input)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    State state = State.SlashNotEncountered;    
    foreach (var c in input.ToCharArray().Reverse())
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case State.SlashNotEncountered:
                if(c == '/')
                {
                    state = State.SlashEncountered;
                }
                break;  
            case State.SlashEncountered:
                if(c != '/')
                {
                    state = State.BuildingResult;
                    result = c.ToString();
                }
                break;  
            case State.BuildingResult:
                result = c + result;
                break;
        }
    }
    return result + "/";
}
```

**Output:**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of code for something that can easily be done with regex or `string.Split()` and `string.LastIndexOf()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out *the last* '/' character, just use String *LastIndexOf* method:

```
  String text = @"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/randomcrap.html";
  String result = text;

  int index = text.LastIndexOf('/'); // <- last '/' if any

  if (index >= 0) // <- if there's '/' within the string, trim it 
    result = text.Substring(0, index + 1);

  ...

  Console.Out.Write(result); // <- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/
```